# SQL: Pull data from two table

Tags: sql

I have two tables which are question_table and student_response( like in the images below). I am having a trouble to come up with a query which can pull out Question, ChosenOption(this will display the actual option from question_table, not just OptionA,OptionB...), and TextResponse. Any help or tip is appreciated. Thank you so much !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kthi1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXPiX.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Steve. I will take a look at it !

Answer (score 1):

do you mean you want something like this?

```
select * from question_table,chosen_table where question_table.QuestionID=chosen_table.ID
```

or

```
select * from chosen_table join question_table on chosen_table.QuestionID = question_table.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next

> `SELECT q.*,sr.choosenoption`
>   `FROM question_table q`
>   `INNER JOIN student_response  sr ON sr.questionID=q.ID`

probably your question will be deleted or something ... is basic SQL logic and also you don't put proper tags.

Put mysql tag on your question :)